How to serve react app within pre-existing Laravel project
I need to try and serve a react app I have within a Laravel project that already exists. I wasn't given any info on how to do this so what I tried to do was build my react project, create a new folder for it within public called react-app, then add a route to the index.html within the react-app folder in public (which is just the build of my react-app) the problem is that the assets from the /react-app/assets and other files aren't being loaded with the index file, how can I fix this?
Route::get('/react-app/{any}', function () {
    return file_get_contents(public_path('react-app/index.html'));
})->where('any', '.*');

Tried to add new route to serve react-app, but the assets aren't loading with it.

Had you got any solution to this?
